# Creating a new variable based on levels of several other variables in R

Tags: r, variables

I´m not very experienced in programming. I´m trying to create a new variable which is comprised of factor levels of 7 existing variables: Here´s an example:

`variables=data.frame(var1=c(0,1,2,3), var2=c(0,1,1,0), var3=c(1,0,1,1), var4=c(001,110,211,301))`

So what I want to create is var4, which is a compound of all levels in each row of var1, var2 and var3. Are there any suggestions for an elegant solution?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in function for this is `interaction()`:

```
transform(variables, var4 = interaction(var1, var2, var3, sep = "", drop = TRUE, lex.order = TRUE))

  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    0    0    1  001
2    1    1    0  110
3    2    1    1  211
4    3    0    1  301
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unite` to combine the columns and use `bind_cols` to add them later to your dataframe like this:

```r
variables=data.frame(var1=c(0,1,2,3), var2=c(0,1,1,0), var3=c(1,0,1,1))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

variables %>% 
  bind_cols(
    variables %>%
      unite("var4", var1:var3, sep = ""))
#>   var1 var2 var3 var4
#> 1    0    0    1  001
#> 2    1    1    0  110
#> 3    2    1    1  211
#> 4    3    0    1  301
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>